# Header not showing using Custom Notification

Tags: android, android-notifications, android-remoteview

I'm using RemoteViews in Android Studio with a custom notification. The only thing is that I'm having issues with it now showing the small icon and the App Name.

Thanks hope I have made some sense?

```
Intent notificationIntent = new Intent(mContext, CardDemoActivity.class);
notificationIntent.setFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TOP | Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_SINGLE_TOP);

PendingIntent pendingIntent = PendingIntent.getActivity(mContext,0,notificationIntent,0);
RemoteViews remoteView = new RemoteViews(mContext.getPackageName(), R.layout.notifcation_player);
remoteView.setImageViewResource(R.id.notif_appIcon, R.drawable.app_logo);
remoteView.setTextViewText(R.id.notif_playing, title);
remoteView.setTextViewText(R.id.notif_preacher, preacher);
NotificationCompat.Builder mBuilder = new NotificationCompat.Builder(mContext);
mBuilder.setSmallIcon(R.drawable.app_logo);
mBuilder.setContent(remoteView);
mBuilder.setContentIntent(pendingIntent);
NotificationManager notificationManager = (NotificationManager) mContext.getSystemService(mContext.NOTIFICATION_SERVICE);
notificationManager.notify(1, mBuilder.build());
```

Comment: what does the layout XML look like?

Comment: https://www.dropbox.com/s/pud1idbb2en3g4o/notifcation_player.xml?dl=0

Answer (score 0):

Use -:

```
mBuilder.setContentTitle("Your tilte");  //title for your project
mBuildersetContentText("Your message);//message you want to show
```

Comment: Yeh mate, I have tried that and it does not show. I'm using a custom layout for the Notification.